# Determine if $P$ is an orthogonal projection matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra

$$
   P=\frac13\begin{bmatrix}
    2 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
    1 & 1 &-1 & 0 \\
    0 & -1 & 2 & 1 \\
    1 &0 & 1 & 1 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$
If it turns out to be an orthogonal projection matrix, find a subspace it's projecting onto.

I have started by checking if $P$=$P^{2}$ and $P$=$P^T$, which came out to be true. How do I proceed?

Comment: If $P=P^2$ then it must be $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$. Is $\dfrac{1}{3}$ a typo?

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales I find that $P=P^2$ with the $\frac13$...

Comment: $ P^2=\frac{1}{9}\begin{bmatrix}
  6 & 3 & 0 & 3 \\
  3 & 3 &-3 & 0 \\
  0 & -1 & 2 & 1 \\
  3 &0 & 3 & 3 \\
 \end{bmatrix}\ne P$

Answer (score 1):

Indeed $P=P^2$ and $P=P^T$, so $P$ is an orthogonal projection matrix. Observe that 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}0\\-1\\2\\1\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}2\\1\\0\\1\end{bmatrix} - 2\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\-1\\0\end{bmatrix}
$$
and
$$
\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\1\\1\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}2\\1\\0\\1\end{bmatrix} - \begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\-1\\0\end{bmatrix},
$$
so $P$ projects onto the subspace spanned by its first two column vectors.

Comment: Thank you! So, what happens in general if I multiply some vector $x$ by a projection matrix? Is its projection then in the column space of the matrix? From your answer, I can see that in fact, those two vectors are the basis of the column space of $P$.

Comment: @Milica If you left-multiply a vector by _any_ matrix the result by definition lies in its column space.

Answer (score 0):

The projection operator $P$ maps its null vectors to the zero vector and all other non-zero vectors to a non-zero vector in $\Bbb R^n$. Hence to find the onto-subspace:

**Step 1**

decompose $P$ to eigenvalues as $$P=QDQ^T$$where $D$ is diagonal and $Q$ is unitary.

**Step 2**

the columns of $Q$ are the eigenvectors of $P$ of which, remove those that do not belong to the kernel of $P$. Call this set $V_{n\times k}$.

**Step 3**

The onto-subspace is $$R=PV=\{w\in\Bbb R^n\ |\  w=\sum_{i}a_iPv_i\ ,\ a_i\in\Bbb R\ ,\ v_i\in V\}$$

Comment: Isn't your first sentence true of any matrix?

Comment: Indeed. And so for $P$!